# Selenium read testdata from file?

Tags: java, selenium, soapui

I'm launching some tests in the webservice test tool soapUI.
Also I want to use Selenium for visual assertions.

I can define a datasource for soapui, eg a textifle, xml, csv, excel etc.

How can I also read the values from selenium?
Selenium runs as html-suites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running as html suites you cannot define a data source. You would need to convert to a programming language of your choice such as Python or Ruby and then read the file in manually.